# Convert string to uniqueidentifier when join is happening

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I want to create a stored procedure but I get an error, after a while found out that "ret_payrollcalculationInfo" includes xml column and stored BankGuid and BankBranchGuid as string, not uniqueidentifier and couldn't Join to their tables.

```
<BankGuid>92434DE6-3D3C-43F1-A89E-869AE5456B07</BankGuid>
<BankBranchGuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</BankBranchGuid>
<PayrollItemGuid>482C44DD-ECFB-4B79-9118-86B681CC51C9</PayrollItemGuid>
<SalariedType>1</SalariedType>
```

I want to know if there is a way to cast uniqeidentifier when INNER JOIN is happening. here is some code...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ret_PayrollCalculations_GetCalculationSummaries]
(
    @CalculationCommandGuid uniqueidentifier,
    @OperationalUnitIDs varchar(512)
)
AS
DECLARE @UnitIds TABLE([ID] INT primary key)
IF ISNULL(@OperationalUnitIDs, '') <> ''
    INSERT INTO @UnitIds SELECT Distinct [Column] FROM com_udfSplit(@OperationalUnitIDs, ',')

SELECT DISTINCT
    calculaion.[PersonnelNo],
    calculaion.[FullName],
    calculaion.[Amount],
    calcInfo.[AccountNo],
    calcInfo.[SalariedType],
    bank.[Title],
    branch.[Title]
FROM
    ret_PayrollCalculationCommands command INNER JOIN
    ret_vwPayrollCalculations calculaion ON command.[Guid] = calculaion.[CalculationCommandGuid] INNER JOIN
    ret_PayrollCalculationInfo calcInfo ON calculaion.[Guid] = calcInfo.[PayrollCalculationGuid] INNER JOIN
    gen_Banks bank ON calcInfo.[BankGuid]   = bank.[Guid] INNER JOIN
    gen_Branches branch ON calcInfo.[BankBranchGuid] = branch.[Title]
WHERE
command.[Guid] = @CalculationCommandGuid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply cast the `VARCHAR` value to a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, for example:

```
CAST('482C44DD-ECFB-4B79-9118-86B681CC51C9' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

So your `JOIN` clauses become something like this:

```
ON command.[Guid] = CAST(calculaion.[CalculationCommandGuid] AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```